# PyCharm: Replace in Files not showing Replacement String in Find Window

Tags: pycharm

In older versions of Pycharm, if you did a Replace in Files on your entire project, you could open the results in the Find Window and then for each result double check that the replacement made sense. It would highlight the string to replace and then right next to it/underneath it in a box would contain the replacement string.

I have just upgraded to the latest version, and this appears to have gone away.

Is it possible to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the replacement regex string I used was incorrect. After correcting it, the replacement string showed up.

It seems like sometimes Pycharm will tell you if the replacement regex string has an error, but other times it does not.